# How to select cell with mouse after DragDrop?

Tags: c#, .net, events, datagridview

I have two datagridviews in my form. A user can select multiple cells and drag them to treeview nodes.

Here is the code of the mouse down event:

```
    private void datagridviews_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {

        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
        {     Console.WriteLine("mouse down right");
            statuslabel.Text = "";

            DataGridView.HitTestInfo hit = ((DataGridView)sender).HitTest(e.X, e.Y);
            if (hit.Type == DataGridViewHitTestType.Cell)
            {
                var clickedCell = ((DataGridView)sender).Rows[hit.RowIndex].Cells[hit.ColumnIndex];
                clickedCell.Selected = true;
            }

            List<string> cellcontents = new List<string>();
            foreach (DataGridViewCell c in ((DataGridView)sender).SelectedCells)
            {
                cellcontents.Add((string)c.Value);
            }

            if (cellcontents.Count>0)
                ((DataGridView)sender).DoDragDrop(cellcontents, DragDropEffects.Copy);
        }
        else
            Console.WriteLine("mouse down left");

    }
```

Drag and drop works but when I click on a cell in the origin datagridview right after the completion of the drop, I have to click twice for a cell to be selected.

Here is the console log of the events - right click is the drag/drop operation, then a normal left mouse click fires the mouse down event but not the cell click event even though I am clicking on a cell.

> mouse down right
>   mouse down left
>   mouse down left
>   cell clicked

Why is the cell clicked event not firing the first time on mouse down left?